# PL-SEM with R. Can someone help me to estimate a second-order construct and the p-values?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am using semPLS to run PL-SEM. I am not sure if semPLS allows me to estimate a second-order construct. In addition, I can't find the p values for the analysis that I have conducted. Can someone guide me on this? Thank you.